# How to implement inputAccessoryView to UITextField in CustomCell using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell, inputaccessoryview

I have a tableView with custom cell and it works perfectly with its own UITableViewCell configured.

In the custom cell there is an UITextField which uses keyboard type of Decimal Pad. So I wanted to add Done button as inputAccessoryView to the keyboard.

I am getting error on when assigning delegate to UITextField, using doneClicked function and textViewDidEndEditing function.

If I implement below code in my ViewController I am not getting any error but only that I cannot use UITextField outlet for in repetitive content (TableView).

Any ideas how to get this work? I appreciate any help!

```
class favCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var deciPadField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.deciPadField.delegate = self

        // Decipad config for adding Done button above
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        let flexiableSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneClicked))
        toolBar.setItems([flexiableSpace, doneButton], animated: false)
        deciPadField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar  
    }


    @objc func doneClicked(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Fixed

Comment: Note that it is Swift convention to name your classes starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: And you just need to end the deciPadField editing  `deciPadField.endEditing(true)` and UIBarButtonSystemItem.whatever is redundant. Just use `.flexibleSpace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **UITextViewDelegate** instead of **UITextFieldDelegate**. 
Then I suggest to set a protocol for your cell and to manage the text field delegate actions in your ViewController.

Comment: You were right. I made a mistake with the delegate. Now errors are gone. When I launch the simulator it seems like it works without any problems. What if I manage actions in the custom view cell?

Comment: Good ;) If you don’t have to handle events or change something in your ViewController you can use it in your custom cell.